# C++ массивы в классах

Tags: c++

```js
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Company {
 private:
 string name;
 const static int Size;
 Company(Size){
  this->Size=Size;
 }
 protected:
 int worker;
 
 public:
  int Array[Size];
};

class Worker : public Company{
 Worker(int a){
  this->worker=a;
 }
};

main(){
 int worker;
 string name;
 cout<<"Name company";
 cin>>name;
 cout<<"Number worker";
 cin>>worker;
 Company Volia(7);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я что то не понял, а что вы от этого хотите, у вас Size - это переменная времени выполнения, ее значение  будет известно только в момент выполнения программы. А C++ язык компилируемый, он в момент компиляции, явно до выполнения, должен точно знать сколько памяти выделить под массиви вы ему этого не сообщили, задав в качестве размера _переменную_

Comment: Я конструктором инициализировал размер массива.Все что мне нужно это что бы я мог задать размер массива с консоли и создался массив в классе.Как это сделать?

Comment: Если размер массива задается во время выполнения, то надо в классе объявить только указатель, а во время выполнения выделить под него память функциями вида malloc или new (как под виндами это сейчас принято, не знаю). И когда класс будет умирать (в его деструкторе), вы должны не забыть освободить выделенную память (free, delete)

Comment: можно пример коду?

Comment: int *Aray;  Array=malloc(sizeof(int) * Size);  Но вообще вам надо срочно искать литературу по языку C и разбираться в механизмах указателей. Ну и вообще самого языка, что бы точно проводить грань между компиляцией и выполнением (конструкторы работают во время выполнения и что вы там в них инициализировали, на ход компиляции ни как не влияет)

Comment: @coder228 Что вы собираетесь хранить в массиве? И должен ли массив меняться в размере в течении жизни объекта, в котором он определен?

Comment: @Mike,окей, вся ночь впереди го скайп?

Comment: @Vlad,не должен меняться )Мне нужно найти обратную матрицу любой размерности

Comment: @coder228 Ночью спать надо, я как раз собираюсь и вам советую. К сожалению, осознание этого факта обычно приходит слишком поздно, когда исправить уже ничего нельзя

Comment: @Mike,у меня есть еще выходные))Завтра го скайп или вк?

Comment: Бррррр.. Жуть...

Comment: @Qwertiy,почему?

Comment: @coder228 Вы так и не ответили, что вы собираетесь хранить в массиве.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, буду хранить int

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, то, что вы хотите получить, в языке C++, точнее, в его недавно принятом стандарте C++11, реализуется через шаблонный параметр, а не через параметр к конструктору. Например, есть класс [std::array](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), и, соответственно, пример кода будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
#include <array>

template <int N>
struct Company {
    std::array<int, N> Array;
};

int main(void) {
    Company<3> companies;
}
```

Но, как видно, и в этом случае N должна быть известна (или, точнее, *вычислима*, для  C++11 и старше [см constexpr](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)) в *момент компиляции*.

Если же размер станет известен только в момент выполнения, то рекомендую воспользоваться типом данных, называемых [std::vector](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). В этом случае, код мог бы выглядеть так:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef> // для std::size_t

class Company {
public:
    Company(std::size_t _size)
        :array(_size)
    {}
    std::vector<int> array;
};
```

Доступ к элементам вектора производится так же, как и к элементам массива, через [], и стоит этот [] столько же, сколько и доступ к элементам массива.

В этом случае вам не нужно самостоятельно заниматься управлением памятью, все new[], delete[] сделают за вас в момент создания и уничтожения объектов класса Company. И это хорошо, потому что позволяет сосредоточиться на решении *своих* задач, а не на рутине борьбы с корректным управлением памятью.

Однако, нужно отчетливо понимать, что vector - 1) структура динамическая, аллоцируемая в динамической памяти (само по себе это явление обыденное, но помнить про это стоит, потому как и память не резиновая и её аллокация и освобождение - процедуры небесплатные) и 2) размер vector'а может быть изменен позднее, через методы resize/push_back/pop_back итп, поэтому выставлять его в таком виде *не рекомендуется*, - я бы сделал его приватным членом класса, а для доступа снаружи обеспечил бы геттеры/сеттеры элементов, но это уже зависит от ваших задач.

Ну и да, какая-нибудь толковая книжка про *современный* C++ не помешает, "оранжевый" или "зеленый" Страуструп 1990-какого-то года издания, ещё Поттосин редактировал, нынче уже представляет скорее букинистический интерес.